# How to display MongoDB Data collection to the index.html page using Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, axios

I tried to fix my backend and rewrote my "get" route with `res.render(data)`, but it still did not work.

Please give me examples on how to do it.

Also, I'm using Axios on my frontend part.

My get route:

```
app.get('/',(req,res) => {
    console.log('Welcome to roffys server')
    Todo.find({}).exec((err,todo)=>{
        if(err) {
            console.log('Error retrieving todos')
        } else {
            res.json(todo)
        }
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put some comments in the bellow code, but to take in account, the data I put there is hardcoded, you need to do get the data with the getTodo function.

```js
const dataFromAPI = [
  {todo: "do homework", status: "complete"}, 
  {todo: "Read a book", status: "incomplete"}
]
const rootApp = document.getElementById("app");

function getTodo () {
// Since I don't will do a call to a API, I comment this, but you need it in your environment.
  //fetch("someUrl")
    //.then(res => res.json())
    //.then(addDataToHtml) addDataToHtml is a function that will receive your data as argument
}

function addDataToHtml(data) {
  data.forEach(task => (
    rootApp.innerHTML += `
      <div>
        <div>
          <span>Task:</span>
          <span>${task.todo}</span>
        </div>
        <div>
          <span>Status:</span>
          <span>${task.status}</span>
        </div>
      </div>`
  ))
}

// I do the call here, but you need to do it in the getTodo function.
addDataToHtml(dataFromAPI);
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
```